# Sending SMS to multiple phone numbers stored in a database

Tags: php, twilio

I was able to successfully set up twilio in my project (pretty straight forward process I know) but I was looking for a way to be able to send SMS to a list of phone numbers stored in a database. Please help I am very new to programming and I know this question may sound very silly to some of you but I really need some help. My appreciations in advance.

below is the code I am using in my project and right now I have it set up to pull the "to" phone number using a post method. I thought of having that field to pull all the data in the database (from the specific column where the phone numbers are store) and spit it in that field using mysql and the split each numbers using an ajax script but then how can I loop the sending process through of the mobile phone numbers? Or if there is simpler way of doing it please let me know, thanks

```
            <?php
                require '../app/init.php';
                use Twilio\Rest\Client;

                $twilio_conn = new mysqli($twilio_host, $twilio_username, $twilio_password, $twilio_db) or die($twilio_conn->error());
                $twilio_result = $twilio_conn->query("SELECT phone_numbers FROM ctn") or die($twilio_conn->error);
                while ($row = $twilio_result->fetch_assoc()):
                    echo '<br><br><br>' . $row['phone_numbers'];
                endwhile;

                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    if(isset($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
                        $client = new Client($config['account_sid'],$config['auth_token']);
                        $client->account->messages->Create($_POST['number'], ['from'=>$config['phone_number'], 'body'=>$_POST['message']]);
                        echo "<br><br><h3 class='text-center bg-success'>Message has been sent</h3>";
                    }
                }
            ?>


                <div class="container col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <form role="form" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <span>Text Message Mainframe</span><br><br>
                            <input name="number" type="tel" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Phone Number to send to">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Message body"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Send Message">
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say, that $phoneNumbers is array of phone numbers, to which you want to send messages.

```
        <?php
            require '../app/init.php';
            use Twilio\Rest\Client;

            $twilio_conn = new mysqli($twilio_host, $twilio_username, $twilio_password, $twilio_db) or die($twilio_conn->error());
            $twilio_result = $twilio_conn->query("SELECT phone_numbers FROM ctn") or die($twilio_conn->error);

            $phoneNumbers = $twilio_result->fetch_assoc()['phone_numbers'];

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                if(isset($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
                    $client = new Client($config['account_sid'],$config['auth_token']);


            foreach($phoneNumbers as $phoneNumber){
            $client->account->messages->Create($phoneNumber, ['from'=>$config['phone_number'], 'body'=>$_POST['message']]);
            }


          echo "<br><br><h3 class='text-center bg-success'>Message has been sent</h3>";
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jakub, this was very helpful, now the last bit of thing I can't figure is how to get the phone numbers from my table into that $phoneNumbers arrays instead of having the data hardcoded. The phone numbers are currently stored in the phone_numbers column

Comment: I think, that this should work, but I'm not sure. Please, check my edited answer and try it.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)